How to Replace Integers and Decimals in Notepad++
The following series of numbers need to be replaced:
 1
10
12.34
10.000
08

And get the following result:
{'1'}
{'10'}
{'12.34'}
{'10.000'}
{'08'}

The search pattern (\d+\.\d+) only works with decimals, but I need a more universal option.

Try the following:

Find what: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
Replace with: {'$1'}
Search mode: Regular expression

This part of the regex (?:\.\d+)? Optionally matches a decimal point followed by one or more digits is for finding the decimal and digits that might follow as they are optional.


Thank you very much! See my answer too

I wrote my own version, but I also like @ReddyLutonadio version. It's simpler.
Find what: (-?(0\d+|0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?)
Replace with: \{'\1'\}


Except the optional minus sign, your regex matches exactly the same things but it's less readable.

Follow what @Toto said, he has plenty of knowledge related to regular expressions.

@ReddyLutonadio Now I will know where to turn for advice and help
